# How to append in terraform output variables to list in root module?

Tags: terraform

we try to implement infrastructure as code with terraform, therefore we have different products bundled as modules with an output variable `users`. Now we want to append all these output variables (list of users) after each module block to a global variable of the root module. How is that possible?

```
variable "users" {
  type = list(string)
  default = []
}

module "product_a" {
  source = "./product_a"
}

var.users = concat(modules.product_a.users, var.users)

module "product_b" {
  source = "./product_b"
}

var.users = concat(modules.product_b.users, var.users)
```

This is not working, there I receive `An argument or block definition is required here. To set an argument, use the
equals sign "=" to introduce the argument value.`

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Terraform variables are not *mutable*, meaning that once you have defined them their variables are fixed. What we can do instead is to create a *new* value derived from the variables and other data you've already defined.

We an assign a name to such an intermediate value using Terraform's [Local Values](https://www.terraform.io/docs/configuration/locals.html) concept:

```
variable "users" {
  type = list(string)
  default = []
}

module "product_a" {
  source = "./product_a"
}

module "product_b" {
  source = "./product_b"
}

locals {
  all_users = concat(
    module.product_a.users,
    module.product_b.users,
    var.users,
  )
}
```

With the above, you can use `local.all_users` to refer to that combined result, while leaving `var.users` unchanged as the original input.

---

The way you presented your question also raises another point: it's important to understand that Terraform is not a sequential programming language, so the order of declaration of these blocks is not significant. I placed the `locals` block in the above example after the two `module` blocks just because it was the smallest change from your given example, but these blocks could actually have been in any order.

Terraform automatically infers the order of operations by analyzing the references: it can automatically determine that `local.all_users` must be evaluated only after `module.product_a.users` and `module.product_b.users` because both of those objects are mentioned in its expression. Furthermore, any objects that you referred to in the `value` arguments in the `output "users"` blocks in those two modules will be understood as dependencies of the output. By following each of these connections Terraform can automatically develop a global understanding of the overall required ordering of operations for all of the objects you declared.

Comment: This will only work if module.product_a.users and module.product_b.users are lists. 
[concat()](https://www.terraform.io/language/functions/concat) takes two or more lists and combines them into a single list - it will not work if the output is a string